# Chart.js update bars of a bar-chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've got a BarChart on my Webpage using Chart.js.

Ive added two datapoints to it using

```
chart.addData([5], "A");
chart.addData([7], "B");
```

Now I want to update those bars A and B without removing them and adding them again (which I already figured out how to do that). I want them to move vertically to adjust to their new values but I cant find out how to access the data thats already in the chart.

Theres nothing like

```
chart.updateData(0,[6]);
chart.updateData(1,[9]);
```

where the first value would be the index of the stored data (f.e.).

How should I do this?

Comment: "Now I want to update those bars A and B without removing them and adding them again (which I already figured out how to do that)" ... oh my ...gawd . besides the obvious flaw in your title and your question .. what is the code you used to "update the bars"

Answer (score 5):

In general, you want to go through your data object, add,delete or replace your elements and then call [.update](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-prototype-methods) , that's it.

Here's an example where I add 2 more columns at the end of a chart:

```
function addData() {
  myBarChart.data.labels[12] ="2017";
  myBarChart.data.labels[13] ="2018";
  myBarChart.data.datasets[0].data[12] = 500;
  myBarChart.data.datasets[0].data[13] = 600;
  myBarChart.update();
}
```

And more specifically to your case, here I modify the value of one year:

```
function adjust2016() {
  myBarChart.data.datasets[0].data[11] = 300;
  myBarChart.update();
}
```

Full Example:

[Codepen Chart.js Add replace data example](http://codepen.io/k3no/pen/gwdYzr?editors=0010)

Comment: Wow Just Cool.This is great